# In iOS 7, how to scroll to the top of a UIScrollView when using a translucent UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, ios7

In iOS 6, you could scroll to the top of a UIScrollView using:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

If you use that code in iOS 7 with a translucent navigation bar, you get a result that is *technically* correct, but not user friendly. The top of the scroll view will be positioned to the origin of the screen.

[image]

How would I position the top of the scroll view to the bottom of the navigation bar instead? I'm looking for a solution that is not hardcoded, because in my application, sometimes the status bar and navigation bar can be hidden. Also, I would like to keep the translucent effect instead of copping out and doing `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using hard-coded values, use the new API:

```
[self.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0)];
```

You are setting the content insets of the scroll view to top and bottom layout guides. So if you have a navigation bar that is 44 points and a status bar of 20 points and no status bar, it will be 64 points top (in portrait) and 0 points bottom.

You should do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: This works. `TopLayoutGuide` is an `id<UILayoutSupport>`, so to get the CGFloat value, you need to use `topLayoutGuide.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this method -> setContentOffset:animated:

```
[_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Comment: Swift: `self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use -60 for the y coordinate or, better yet, get the statusbar and navigation bar heights dynamically because they both change.

See UIApplication's statusBarFrame and self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds, I think.